# Add the shadow on blogger images in just some photos

Tags: html, css

by default, Blogger's Simple Template comes with a box/shadow around images. You can see them around images in any Blogger blog that hasn't edit it, like this one:

http://conalmadefiesta.blogspot.com.es/

I found a code to completely remove it:

```
.post-body img, .post-body .tr-caption-container, .Profile img, .Image img,
.BlogList .item-thumbnail img {
  padding: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  background: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
}
```

And also I have found a code to remove it only in some images. Adding the class **noborder** on the html of every post with an image, and this in the css:

```
img.noborder {
    border: 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: none;
}
```

I want to do JUST the opposite: find a code that doesn't show the shadow by default but that it does when I try add a class (let's say: border) to the image.

Any ideas on how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: to remove `box-shadow`, just use `box-shadow:none;`, instead of what you have on the 2nd code. also I recommend not using `!important` if you do not have to.

Comment: Do you have access to the css files containing the shadows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it yet! You've got the code to remove the shadows, so thinking a little you can make the opposite (I'm using `:not()` pseudoselector in CSS):

```
/* remove all boxshadows except tags with "border" classname */
.post-body img:not(.border), .post-body .tr-caption-container:not(.border), .Profile img:not(.border), .Image img:not(.border),
.BlogList .item-thumbnail img:not(.border) {
  padding: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  background: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
}
```

So if you need to put a box shadow in some img you can add `border` class:

```
<img src="img.png" class="border">
```

It works!

See more information about `:not()` selector:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot

Comment: It works, but you need to add the border class to images that you need to show the border. Can we see your code? What is the problem? "It doesn't work" don't help me to know what happen.

Comment: Glup, sorry, it does work! Thanks so much Marcos! I am just starting out with coding, I didnt know the :not() thing, I am gonna read about it. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Yeah, congratulations. Come with me when you need a solution for CSS or javascript problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

you should like this -

```
.post-body img.noborder , .Profile img.noborder , .Image img.noborder , .BlogList .item-thumbnail img.noborder {
border: 0px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
background: none;
}
```

or you can use `!important`-

```
img.noborder {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .0) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .0) !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .0) !important;
}
```

Comment: OP needs the opposite. This answer is the same that OP asks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to create an other class called `.border` with:

```
.border {    
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

And then add this class to images that you want with shadows.
In this case, you should ignore this:

```
img.noborder {
    border: 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: none;
}
```

And leave:

```
.post-body img, .post-body .tr-caption-container, .Profile img, .Image img,
.BlogList .item-thumbnail img {
  padding: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  background: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
}
```

Here, the images will not have shadows except for those with `.border`